# How about building a C# unit test project in CMake?

Tags: c#, c++, unit-testing, cmake

I used the following methods, but I failed.
How to solve it? Or is there another way?
Looking forward to your reply. Thanks!!!

This is my CMake project:

1. dotnet_xunit_template.csproj.in

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectName>@PROJECT_NAME@</ProjectName>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    @source_files_string@
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

2. UnitTest1.cs

```
using Xunit;

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        int i = 0;
        i = 2;
    }
}
```

3. CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(xunitproject)

set(source_files_string)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/*.cs)

foreach(item ${SRC_FILES})
    # <Compile Include="exe_test.cs" />
    set(source_files_string
        "${source_files_string}<Compile Include=\"${item}\" />
        "
    )
endforeach()

configure_file(dotnet_xunit_template.csproj.in ${PROJECT_NAME}.csproj @ONLY)

include_external_msproject(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}.csproj
)
```

Build the project into Visual Studio 2017, and the error message is as follows:

```
Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.  ZERO_CHECK  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets  186
```

Comment: It seems like your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would prefer to use netcoreapp2.1 instead of v4.0.

Comment: @geodoer: It seems you have already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70112278/how-about-creating-a-c-sharp-unit-test-in-cmake) on this topic and have found additional information about the problem. Please note, that proper Stack Overflow workflow in that case is to **edit** the existed question rather than asking a new question (and deleting the old one).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I feel very sorry, this is the first time for me to use Stack Overflow, and I will not have such problems in the future. Thank you very much!